# Using a Matrix vs. creating a new Bitmap

Tags: android, performance, bitmap, android-canvas

I am working on an android game and am trying to optimize it's speed as much as possible. 
I was wondering if it is any faster, when drawing on a canvas, to create a new bitmap before onDraw than giving t he canvas the bitmap and matrixand having it scale the image during onDraw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that depends.. If you paint the image with the same scale factor and rotation a 1000 times, you might be better of rotating/scaling the image once and draw the scaled image a 1000 times.

If you have a different transform for each image than I'd definitely go for the matrices. Creating a new image involves memory allocation / dellocation and garbage collection kicking in, which you don't have for the matrix approach.

But writing a benchmark to find out takes about 15 minutes and you could share the results here ;)